# Foreground service stops on killing app

Tags: android, service, foreground-service

I have added below code in `onStartCommand` of service-

```
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(AbcService.this)
            .setContentTitle("xyz")
            .setTicker("xyz")
            .setContentText("xyz")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.mevo_chat_mevopic)
            .setOngoing(true).build();
    startForeground(AppConstants.ABC,
            notification);
```

and         `stopForeground(true);` inside `onDestroy()` of service.I expect service to run even when app is destroyed as it is foreground service but i see that sometimes it runs and sometimes it gets stopped.I don't have any other apps open and my device doesn't have memory issue.What could be possible reasons for my foreground service being stopped and how can i resolve this?

Comment: I found this if it can help: https://gist.github.com/Galarzaa90/5296804256f96a8d1d74d2432ce74fd2

Answer (score -2):

If your Service is started by your app then actually your service is running on main process. so when app is killed service will also be stopped. So what you can do is, send broadcast from onTaskRemoved method of your service as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.ServiceStopped");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

and have an broadcast receiver which will again start a service. I have tried it. service restarts from all type of kills.